# How to set up Set-up.exe?

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to download Photoshop CS6, but I can't find Setup.exe on my computer. I'm still new to Ubuntu, so I need help. Any advice would help me right now.

I've followed instructions on the forum, but I don't know where to find Setup.exe if I even have it! Where is it found? And what do you do if it isn't there? I'm desperate for Photoshop now, and since my Wacom is coming soon, I'd like to have Photoshop to work with it.

Comment: Are you going to run the executable in Wine or something as `exe` is only on Windows?

Comment: Photoshop is not available for Ubuntu. It's also not free. You have to buy it to get the disc to install it from.

Comment: @dobey or use GIMP instead, which is Free Software.

Comment: See https://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?appId=17 and http://www.ubuntufree.com/top-5-photoshop-alternatives-on-ubuntu-14-04-and-14-10/

Comment: @dobey - So ? the OP may have the disk and may be trying to install it.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen So? The question does not clearly state so. If that is the case, then one should state so. And even then, it's still a duplicate of "how do I install windows apps on Ubuntu?"

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer your actual question, but please see all the comments above and understand that you cannot simply install Photoshop CS6 directly on Ubuntu.

You say you are "downloading" Photoshop CS6 as opposed to installing from disc. If it is coming from a legit source like Adobe.com AND you downloaded the Windows not Mac version, you'll have downloaded two large files (about 1.0 - 1.1 GB each), one is a .7z file and one a .exe file. The .exe file will *not* be called "setup.exe" but will have a longer name like "Photoshop_13_LS4.exe" or similar. You double click this file to begin the installation.

But again, please see the advice provided in the comments before you do this otherwise it will not work for you at all.